# Find the approximation of an inverse of sum of two special matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

Given $K$ is a psd symmetric covariance matrix. Is there any way that we can  approximate $(I+K)^{-1}$ by $K$. Where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

@ Phong Le , this question was asked dozens of times on this site. In general, the answer is $(I+K)^{-1}=I-K+K^2-\cdots$ that is practically a bad answer.

Assume that $K$ is symmetric $>0$ and $spectrum(K)=\lambda_1\geq \cdots\geq \lambda_n>0$. Then $cond(I+K)=\dfrac{1+\lambda_1}{1+\lambda_n}\approx 10^k$. If $K$ is known with $p$ significant digits, then the calculation of  $(I+K)^{-1}$ has complexity $\sim n^3/2$ and the result has $p-k$ significant digits.

Now assume that $||K||<1$ ; then $k=0$ and we want $p$ significant digits. The formula $(I+K)^{-1}=I-K+K^2+R$ where $||R||<||K||^3$ is useless because the complexity of the calculation of $I-K+K^2$ is $\sim n^3/2$. It remains the formula $(I+K)^{-1}=I-K+R$ where $||R||<||K||^2$ ; it is convenient if $||K||^2<10^{-p}$, that is if $||K||=\lambda_1<10^{-p/2}$.

Conclusion: except if $K$ is very small, the best you can do is: calculate $(I+K)^{-1}$.